# How to create setup from multiple exe in c#?

Tags: c#, installation

I can create the setup file from c# but I want to make the multiple steps of setup.
For example, the users install first setup and then the second one respectively.

Anyone can gives me any advice?

Comment: I don't understand what you are describing. A solution can have multiple projects, each of which can be installed using the same VS Installer. Is this what you mean: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c.aspx

Comment: Do you want to make an installer or something similar to import wizard?

Comment: I mean I want to make two installations in one installer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a bootstrapper.

One solution is to use [Burn](http://wix.sourceforge.net/)

Another one uses [MsBuild:](http://codeprairie.net/blogs/chrisortman/archive/2008/04/16/using-msbuild-to-create-a-bootstrapper-for-you-installer.aspx)